# Not able to import pacakes in azure automation running notebook?

Tags: python, azure, automation, package, pyodbc

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not able to import packages in Azure running notebook.
I install pyodbc and request packages through .whl files by following this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/python-3-packages?tabs=py3.

Packages install successfully for python version 10, by when trying to import in a notebook it give no module found.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is that it cannot find the module named "requrests".

This looks like a misspelling of "requests"

Comment: After  `requests` still the same issue. so I deploy python script on Azure Functions and its working fine.